I keep getting the error "The AWS ECS container todo-ecr-container does not exist" even though the container exists in my task definitions
I am learning about AWS codepipelne for the first time so I am a bit sloppy, but I am trying to build and deploy an artifact to I guess ECS? But I keep getting this error "The AWS ECS container todo-ecr-container does not exist" Even though it exists.


The first screenshot is of a Task Definition. You named it todo-ecr-container but it is not a container, it is a Task Definition. The error seems to imply something is looking for an actual running container on ECS with that name, not a Task Definition.  You haven't provided nearly enough information for anyone to be able to help you solve your issue.

Check your task definition's container name, it should be "todo-ecr-container" as on your first screenshot. Take your attention for extra spaces and capitalization, it matters as well.

There is a difference between task definition and container. Your screenshot is showing the Task Definition.
Inspect the Task Definition, on the first tab there will be Containers section that will give you the Container name and its image.
To double check, validate the JSON tab, look for something like

{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-2:1234567890123:task-definition/todo-ecr-container:1",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "todo-ecr-container",
            "image": "1234567890123.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/todo-ecr-container:latest",
            "cpu": 128,
            "memory": 160,
...

